# Google reCAPTCHA not working in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, forms, recaptcha, fancybox-2

I am trying to use new googles reCAPTCHA in model popup with fancybox (in localhost), but it does not appear. Any idea?

```
var html = "<form method='post'><input type='text' name='nombre' autofocus required placeholder='Escribe tu nombre'/><br><input type='mail' name='mail' placeholder='Escribe tu correo'><br> <input type='tel' name='telefono' placeholder='Escribe tu teléfono'/><br><textarea  rows='5' cols='35' name='mensaje' required placeholder='Escribe tu mensaje'/></textarea><br><div align='center' class='g-recaptcha' data-theme='dark' data-sitekey='XXXX'></div> <input type='checkbox' required name='condiciones' value='condiciones' /> Acepto las <a href='/wordpress/politica-de-privacidad' target='_blank'>condiciones de uso</a> <br /><input type='submit' value='Enviar' /></form>";
        $(".contacto").fancybox({
            'width': 600,
            'height': 500,
            'autoSize': false,
            type: "html",
            content: html,
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    locked: false,
                    css: {
                        'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)',    
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is the code for displaying the captcha?

Comment: The captcha code are inside the "var html".

Comment: I see only a related DIV class: `<div align='center' class='g-recaptcha'...`

Comment: In google documentation ( https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) says that with this class and adding js it goes :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Muggles , my new code. You can copy and paste in Sublime Text (or another text editor).

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a class="contacto">Contacto</a>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var onloadCallback = function () {
                grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
                    'sitekey': '6LflpAUTAAAAANmiwCBqE_EdNVkOitOFmGLoc9LG'
                });
            };
            var html = "<form method='post'> <div id='html_element'></div></form>";
            $(".contacto").fancybox({
                'width': 600,
                'height': 500,
                'autoSize': false,
                type: "html",
                content: html,
                helpers: {
                    overlay: {
                        locked: false,
                        css: {
                            'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)',

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I solve the problem adding form in HTML with "display:none" and ID.In javascript code i put this id in the $html variable.  If is necessary i will put complete code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to dynamically render the the ReCAPTCHA once you have created the Fancybox with the target captcha element. So make sure you have included the necessary javascript (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit) then use the render function like so:

```
grecaptcha.render(
'targetelement', {
'sitekey' : 'XXXX',
'theme' : 'dark'
}
);
```

See for more examples/available parameters
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display?csw=1#example
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display?csw=1#render_param

Comment: I add this script and id with target element in the form but doesn´t work,

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre can you post the code you've used?